# How to write a binary search that looks for words in a list

Tags: python, binary, dataset, binary-search

I was wondering how to write a binary search that looks for the most popular baby names from 2009 - 2014, the names are stored in a list and then I when I receive a prompt asking for what i would like to search for then i would type in the name and it would give how many times it iterated over to find the certain name, and also the names are in JSON format and alphabetical so i can compare characters.I'm planning to write this in python 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
termToFind = input("What would you like to find? ")
    tempMeds = []
for me in allMeds:
   if len(me) >= len(termToFind):
   tempMeds.append(me)
findLength = len(termToFind)
currentPos = len(tempMeds) // 2
stop = False
iterations = 0
amountFound = 0
prevVal = ""
```

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to [give you teh codez](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question).

Comment: i have the list containing the names, and another empty array I'm going to put it in. @MoonCheesez

Comment: i just updated the code @MoonCheesez

Comment: So is the data in JSON format or in a python list? If it is in a JSON format, have you parsed it? What have you parsed it to? Could you give a sample of your data?

Comment: i haven't parsed it at all, i just have it in a list and want to type in a name of something in the list and then have it bisect the list checking for if the character to the left or right of it has what I'm looking for then divide that in half and do the same thing over and over again. @MoonCheesez

Comment: Could you give a sample of your data? @ProgrammingCuber

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use a binary search? What if you used [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Just pass your list (doesn't matter if it's sorted or not) of baby names to `Counter` and then lookup whatever name you're interested in:

```
import json
from collections import Counter

json_baby_names = '["aardvark", "apple", "apple", ...., "zeus"]'
baby_name_counts = Counter(json.loads(json_baby_names))

>>> baby_name_counts['apple']
2
```

If you want the most popular name, you can use `Counter.most_common()`:

```
>>> baby_name_counts.most_common(1)
[('apple', 2)]
```

Comment: the reason i want use a binary search is because I think it would be good practice for me to get familiar with them so i can use them later in other programs i write.  @mhawke